# width = 100% not properly working in IE, Microsoft edge browser

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, media-queries, microsoft-edge

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqPMr.png)I am facing some strange problem in edge and all other IE versions.The problem is that I declare a div and set some property on that div.Initially I set width: 1140px but when the screen resize to its max-width: 1200px I set the div width:100%.All this changes are working perfectly in chrome,firefox,opera,safari but when I test this code in edge or any IE versions it takes too much space on the right side of the device screen.

```css
header{
width: 100%;
height: 500px;
position: relative;
}

.beast-text-box {
position: absolute;
width: 1140px;
height: auto;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
-webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
text-align: center;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
.beast-text-box {
width: 100%;
}
}
```

```html
<header>
    <div class="beast-text-box">
        <h1 class="heading-h1">TRAIN LIKE A BEAST</h1>
        <a href="#" class="btn-full js--scroll-to-plan">BEAST                      MODE</a>
        <a href="#" class="btn-full js--scroll-to-start">SHOW ME                   MORE</a>
    </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Can you replicate your problem in a code snippet ?

Comment: I replicate my problem in a code snippet

Answer (score 2):

`transform` is causing issue in IE. Try below CSS to `.beast-text-box` in media.

```
position: relative;
left: 0;
transform: translate(0);
```

```css
header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.beast-text-box {
  position: absolute;
  max-width: 1140px;
  height: auto;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
  .beast-text-box {
    width: 100%;
    /*Added this CSS*/
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    transform: translate(0);
    /*Added this CSS*/
  }
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="beast-text-box">
    <h1 class="heading-h1">TRAIN LIKE A BEAST</h1>
    <a href="#" class="btn-full js--scroll-to-plan">BEAST                      MODE</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn-full js--scroll-to-start">SHOW ME                   MORE</a>
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 1):

I made the following changes and it started working! There a semi-colon missing in `header` CSS and instead of `width: 1140px;` i changed to `max-width: 1140px;`. What i guess happend is, `left: 50%` and `width: 1140px` together are adding to the total width and forcing the horizontal scrollbar to show up in IE11.

```css
header{
width: 100%;
height: 500px;
position: relative;
overflow:hidden;
}

.beast-text-box {
position: absolute;
max-width: 1140px;
height: auto;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
-webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
text-align: center;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
.beast-text-box {
width: 100%;
}
}
```

```html
<header>
    <div class="beast-text-box">
        <h1 class="heading-h1">TRAIN LIKE A BEAST</h1>
        <a href="#" class="btn-full js--scroll-to-plan">BEAST                      MODE</a>
        <a href="#" class="btn-full js--scroll-to-start">SHOW ME                   MORE</a>
    </div>
</header>
```

Comment: If i used max-width:1140px it is OK. But content inside the div are broken when I resize my browser.I just want that remove horizontal scrollbar.

Comment: @MehediHasanMethun if you don't want the horizontal scrollbar, then add `overflow: hidden` to `header`. I updated the code.Check and let me know

Comment: thank you sir you are a life savior.For this reason i got hard reject from themeforest but now i learn a new things...

Comment: We learn from mistake! If it helped accept and upvote the answer.. thanks!